# Make setup.py from subdirectory prefix imports with broader namespace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, namespaces, setuptools

I'm using Python 3.7 and I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
a
  b
    __init__.py
    c.py
    setup.py
```

I'd like to construct a `setup.py` that will allow me to run `pip install -e .` from within the `b` subdirectory and then be able to do:

```
from a.b import c
```

I've been struggling with this for hours (trying various sets of arguments to `find_packages` and `find_namespace_packages`) and I haven't been able to figure out a way to make this work — I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of setuptools. Any advice would be appreciated — thanks!

Comment: Start with an example that works, then slowly and carefuly modify it bit by bit until you get what you want. But honestly why this weird directory structure? I wouldn't recommend you to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to start with a different project structure:

```
project_dir
    a
      b
        __init__.py
        c.py
    setup.py
```

In `setup.py` use `setuptools.find_packages()` or list all your packages and subpackages explicitly:

```
packages=['a', 'a.b'],
```